# CSS Stylesheet Loading Wrong

Tags: html, css, asp.net, infragistics

My original css stylesheet like below ;

http://i.hizliresim.com/o0lg29.png ( Original css )

However when i start my asp.net c# application, it shows wrong css information like below ;

http://i.hizliresim.com/77ZkE5.png ( Wrong css )

Comment: What is exactly the error? The background-color?

Comment: @thescion All of the things that i change in stylesheet.css are not applying when i start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be caused by caching, try pressing `ctrl + F5` to remove cache, and see if the problem is fixed.

Comment: yes, it worked. however, even if i reboot my computer same error happens.

Comment: @JohnHanrick The cache is managed by the browser itself, so restarting your computer will not clear it, it will only be cleared from the browser.

Comment: @JohnHanrick Kindly mark it as the correct answer for future references.

Comment: One more thing. In Chrome, while inspecting the page (F12 was pressed) go to Network tab and check Disable cache checkbox to prevent caching.